# How can I align three box in same line using flexbox in css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my project, I want to design a shipping address design with HTML and css(flexbox). And i want to design "city","zip code","state", box in one line like this  [image: like this]

but in my code, I am unable to do like that design so help me to what changes should I have done to get that result?
And my code results shows is like this  [image: like this]

So I want "city","zip code","state" box takes same size fit to the "ad

**Here is my code**

```css
.shipping-containers {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  background: lightskyblue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-wrapper>form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.shipping-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 15rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-div input {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-wrapper input {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shipping-containers">
  <div class="shipping-wrapper">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder=" name" />
      <input type="text" placeholder=" address" />
      <div class="shipping-div">
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder=" city" class="shipping-input" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder=" zip code " class="shipping-input" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder=" state" class="shipping-input" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder=" Country" class="shipping-input" />
      <button>Continue</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I advise CSS-Grid for this

Comment: yeah sure . but now can i  do this without using css grid here

Comment: yes, it is just super hacky, especially with the code you wrote. Let me completely write it from scratch.

Comment: Could you describe why you don't want to use CSS grid? The layout you require is a grid so it seems the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have many borders included which are a mess to take into account. The easiest and cleanest solution is to use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`. With that property, we don't have to take all the different borders into account.
2. You nested way too many Flexbox and used unnecessary div's. As such I removed all div's out of your form.
3. I used `flex-wrap: wrap` on your form. Then I raised the width from all the inputs to `100%` and created the space left and right with padding on the form.
4. I changed `justify-content: center` to `justify-content: space-between` for your form.
5. I changed the `flex-direction: column` on the form to default `row` as otherwise, the `flex-wrap` will not work.
6. The width for the 3 small inputs must be calculated (that's why CSS-Grid would have been a better and easier solution). YOu have to take the 2x gaps a 10px each into account. So the width for the 3 elements in total is `100% - 20px`. That again must then be divided by 3:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.shipping-containers {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  background: lightskyblue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-wrapper > form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.shipping-wrapper input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.shipping-wrapper input:nth-child(3),
.shipping-wrapper input:nth-child(4),
.shipping-wrapper input:nth-child(5) {
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);
}

.shipping-wrapper button {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="shipping-containers">
  <div class="shipping-wrapper">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="address">
      <input type="text" placeholder="city">
      <input type="text" placeholder="zip code">
      <input type="text" placeholder="state">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Country">
      <button>Continue</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take. Points to note: `box-sizing: border-box` is a must for the inputs.
`.shipping-div` has negative margin so children with margin would align to width (this is bootstrap trick). And the rest is trivial.

```css
.shipping-containers {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background: #ff00007f;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shipping-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.shipping-wrapper>form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.shipping-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.shipping-div>div {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shipping-wrapper input {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="shipping-containers">
  <div class="shipping-wrapper">
    <form>

      <input type="text" placeholder=" name" />
      <input type="text" placeholder=" address" />

      <div class="shipping-div">
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder=" city" class="shipping-input" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder=" zip code " class="shipping-input" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder=" state" class="shipping-input" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="text" placeholder=" Country" class="shipping-input" />

      <button>Continue</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```